# Property [order_number] does not exist on this collection instance. laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to print out queried results from my db to a view after successfully making payments.
However, when i try to access the data passed to the view, i get the error below

`Property [order_number] does not exist on this collection instance.`

I already did `var_dump` on the collection, and it returns the properties and values, but when i try to access it like so `$orderDetails->column_name` i get an error

below is my method

```
  public function complete(Request $request)
{

    $paymentId = $request->input('paymentId');
    $payerId = $request->input('PayerID');

    $status = $this->payPal->completePayment($paymentId, $payerId, $request->order_number);

    $order_number = $request->order_number;

    $order = Order::where('order_number', $order_number)->first();
    $order->status = 'processing';
    $order->payment_status = 1;
    $order->payment_method = 'PayPal';
    $order->save();

    Cart::clear();

    $orderDetails = Order::where('order_number', $order_number)->get();

    return view('frontend.pages.order-success', [
        'orderDetails' => $orderDetails
    ]);

    // return redirect()->route('/')->with('message', 'Your Order has been placed successfully! We will contact you with the details you provided');
}
```

and here is my view page

```
    @extends('frontend.layouts.main')

    @section('title', 'Order Successful')

 @section('content')
 <!-- Main Content -->
 <div id="main-content" class="site-main clearfix">

     <section class="order-detail themesflat-section">
         <div class="themesflat-container">
             <div class="top-order text-center">
                 <h5 class="heading">Congratulation! You’ve completed payment.</h5>
                 <div class="order-infor">
                     <div class="item number">
                         <div class="title">Order Number</div>
                         <div class="content">
                             {{ $orderDetails->order_number }}
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="item date">
                         <div class="title">Date</div>
                         <div class="content">12 August 2020</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="item total">
                         <div class="title">Total</div>
                         <div class="content"></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="item payment">
                         <div class="title">Payment Method</div>
                         <div class="content">Check Payments</div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="main-order">
                 <div class="heading">Order Details</div>
                 <table class="table-order">
                     <tbody>
                         <tr class="title">
                             <th class="product-infor">Product</th>
                             <th class="price">Price</th>
                         </tr>


                         <tr class="item">
                             <td>
                                 <div class="title-product"><a href="#"></a></div>
                             </td>
                             <td class="price">
                                 <div class="price-inner"></div>
                             </td>
                         </tr>


                     </tbody>
                 </table>
             </div>
         </div>
     </section>

 </div><!-- /#main-content -->
 @endsection
```

Comment: `$orderDetails` is a collection, not a single record. Use `first()` instead of `get()`, or use a loop on your blade.

Comment: `$order` is a variable with the order, `$orderDetails` a collection with only 1 item, that same order. I would suggest reading the Eloquent documentation.

Comment: Could it be `$request->input('order_number');` like the other attempts to get data from the request?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get properties from a collection, not from a single item then it won't work.

change:

```
$orderDetails = Order::where('order_number', $order_number)->get();
```

by:

```
$orderDetails = Order::where('order_number', $order_number)->firstOrFail();
```